# Sorting a dictionary of objects by the result of algebraic operation

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Say that, I have this class defined:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Assuming attributes x, y hold integer values, I have a dictionary of 'A' objects - let's call 'a_dict'. I want to sort this dictionary based on the result of an algebraic operation by x and y. I tried this:

```
a_dict_sorted = sorted(a_dict.values(), key=100*int(operator.attrgetter('x')) / (float(operator.attrgetter('x')) + float(operator.attrgetter('y')))
```

Apparently `operator.attrgetter` returns a callable object, rather than the value of that attribute.  So the code above gives this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'operator.attrgetter'
```

Is there any gotcha to sort a dictionary like that? Or I have to preprocess it to create the algebraic results first then sort accordingly?

Comment: Dictionaries can't be sorted. You'll need a `OrderedDict` first. But do you really have a dict or a list?

Comment: `operator.attrgetter('x')` is a function. It can't be the argument of the `int()` function. Consider using lambdas.

Comment: @PauloBu You can take a dictionary's keys or values, and produce a sorted list of those. That's exactly what OP is trying to do, you're just fretting over terminology.

Comment: @Paulo Bu: I need a constant time access to each object, so I put the collection of objects into a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: @delnan This phrase: _Is there any gotcha to sort a dictionary like that in place?_  in the question was what made me think about that, _in place_ means to me that he wants to keep the data structure, not get a new list.

Comment: @PauloBu Point taken.

Comment: @Paulo Bu: Sorry about the language. However, I guess it is clear what I am trying to do by the given example.

Comment: @israkir no problem! I was trying to clarify things for myself because I messed up a little with the terminology indeed. I wasn't sure how you were storing the elements nor how do you want to output them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably better using some anonymous function aka `lambda`

```
a_dict_sorted = sorted(a_dict.values(), key = lambda a: 100*int(a.x/(a.x + a.y)) )
```